# vuejs v-cloak placement while assets download

Tags: vue.js

Currently I'm making vuejs SPA, and the build size is pretty big, so I want to place some loading indicator instead of blank page while vue is downloading its assets.

I've found out that in this case, the solution is v-cloak, but what I dont understand is, in every example the v-cloak is putted inside index.html, whereas in my project src there are no index.html, there is only main.js and vue.app.

there are index.html, but is located inside public folder(which i think its a build file?).

nevertheless, I've tried to put v-cloak directive inside Vue.app, and its still showing blank page while vue downloading its assets. please point me in the right direction.
thanks for all the help.

here's my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <div v-cloak>

   <div class="v-cloak--inline"> <!-- Parts that will be visible before compiled your HTML -->
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
   </div>

   <div class="v-cloak--hidden"> <!-- Parts that will be visible After compiled your HTML -->
      <!-- Rest of the contents -->
      <router-view />
   </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--block {
  display: block;
}
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--inline {
  display: inline;
}
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--hidden {
  display: none;
}
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.v-cloak--block,
.v-cloak--inline,
.v-cloak--inlineBlock {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

and when I put some loading indicator in public/index.html, it work, but how do I remove it after vue finished loading?
heres my public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= webpackConfig.name %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= webpackConfig.name %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    Loading
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-cloak` is supposed to be used on the application's mounting point (the `el`  specified in `new Vue()`), not within a component. Vue does not process `v-cloak` anywhere else but the mounting point, so it has no effect in `App.vue`.

To use `v-cloak`:

1. In `public/index.html`, add the `v-cloak` attribute to `div#app`, and a `<style>` block to hide it:

   ```html
   <div id="app" v-cloak></div>

   <style>
   [v-cloak] {
     display: none;
   }
   </style>
   ```
2. Adjacent to `div#app`, add a loading icon, and style it so that it's hidden when the `v-cloak` attribute is removed (i.e., `:not([v-cloak])`):

   ```html
   <div class="loading">
     <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
   </div>

   <style>
   .loading {
     display: grid;
     place-content: center;
   }
   #app:not([v-cloak]) ~ .loading {
     display: none;
   }
   </style>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-v-cloak-with-a-loading-indicator-ompqn?file=/public/index.html:734-1236)